# Split Rows with Multiple Prod Cols to Multiple Rows with single Prod Col

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have a series of single rows where the product information is held in four different columns.
I want to turn this into multiple rows, with a single product column.

Here's a screenshot of the sheet - with the data at the top and what I am wanting to achieve, below that:

[image: Sample Data]

[This sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vQgn9L_sN1lnBR4H-MZB8JTFCxZQb-FzJSi2n58SPnA/edit?usp=sharing) is Shared with anyone who has the link.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yse:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(ISBLANK(G2:J6),, 
 A2:A6&"♦"&B2:B6&"♦"&C2:C6&"♦"&D2:D6&"♦"&G2:J6&"♦"&G1:J1)), "♦")), 
 "where Col5 <> 0", 0))
```

[image]

Comment: That's a beautiful thing! Thank you 

Comment: I just read the note on your profile, and was sad to see you have not been receiving the recognition you deserve. All the very best! If you ever reach out to me, I would be happy to connect outside of stackoverlfow - @jmsinnz